# HashMap vs ConcurrentHashMap: transfer between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, happens-before

I have a question about using maps in multithreaded application. Suppose we have such scenario:

1. Thread receives json data as `List<Map<String, Object>>` which is deserialized by Jackson Json.
2. This thread *modifies* received maps.
3. And then puts list into blocking queue to be consumed by another thread.

As you can see, map is modified only by single thread, but then it "becomes" read-only (nothing chagnes, just not modified anymore) and passed to another thread. Next, when I looked into implementations of `HasMap` (also `TreeMap`) and `ConcurrentHashMap`, the latter has `volatile` fields while first two isn't. So, which implementation of `Map` should I use in this case? Does `ConcurrentHashMap` is overkill choice or it *must* be used due to inter-thread transfer?

My simple tests shows that I can use `HashMap/TreeMap` when they are modified synchronously and it works, but my conclusion or my test code may be wrong:

```
def map = new TreeMap() // or HashMap
def start = new CountDownLatch(1)
def threads = (1..5)
println("Threads: " + threads)
def created = new CountDownLatch(threads.size())
def completed = new CountDownLatch(threads.size())
threads.each {i ->
    new Thread({
        def from = i * 10
        def to = from + 10
        def local = (from..to)
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + " " + local)
        created.countDown()
        start.await()
        println('Mutating by ' + local)
        local.each {number ->
            synchronized (map) {
                map.put(number, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt())
            }
            println(Thread.currentThread().name + ' added ' + number +  ': ' + map.keySet())
        }
        println 'Done: ' + Thread.currentThread().name
        completed.countDown()
    }).start()
}

created.await()
start.countDown()
completed.await()
println('Completed:')
map.each { e ->
    println('' + e.key + ': ' + e.value)
}
```

Main thread spawns 5 child threads which updates common map synchronously, when they complete main thread successfully sees all updates by child threads.

Comment: Note that in practice most of this should be done with an executor instead.

Comment: You can always wrap the map into immutable ones with `Collections.immutableMap(Map map)`. That way, you are sure that no concurrent modification can ever happen.

Comment: @cybersoft Immutable data structures are inherently thread-safe due to their nature of not being able to change, at all.

Comment: @cybersoft If you keep a reference to the underlying collection and mutate it, your data structure is no longer *immutable*. You just poked a giant, glaring hole into its immutability. But Op explicity said that the data *is not modified*, and wrapping it into an immutable collection and then *keeping **only** the immutable* references gives you the needed guarantee of immutability.

Comment: @Polygnome that fact that an object is immutable does not equate to the fact that it safe from memory visibility issues. Take a POJO with no setter, it is immutable. But if its fields are not `final` nor `volatile` this does not buy you any concurrency guarantee either! Immutability as you do it here (e.g. wrap with `unmodifiableMap`) leave the original map structurally unchanged, and just as safe or unsafe as it ever was. If you want concurrency safe constructs, it's just not enough. You need immutability + safe publication and/or an "happens-before" (java.util.concurrent stuff).

Comment: @güriösä there are definitely concurrency guarantees needed in both the OP's scenario and his test code (which are completely different scenarios by the way).

Comment: @güriösä What if consuming thread is part of fixed thread pool (they're alive forever), but producing threads of count 1...N are periodically created short lived ones?

Comment: Also if n producers get created periodically while the consumers live forever, the blocking queue guarantees proper producer-consumer behavior. But you'll likely need a thread save structure instead of List<Map<String, Object>> for multiple producers at a time, e.g. ConcurrentLinkedList

Comment: Re, "... it "becomes" read-only..." After a program has finished populating some mutable object, and after it _[safely publishes](http://what-when-how.com/Tutorial/topic-355vueju/Java-Concurrency-in-Practice-80.html)_ the changes that it made, we say from that point on that the object is _effectively immutable._

Comment: @GPI the wrapper returned by `Collections.unmodifiableMap(…)` uses a `final` field. If you only access the original map through that field (which implies never modifying the original map after the wrapper’s creation), you have the guarantees of immutable objects. However, there’s rarely a benefit in omitting safe publication.

Answer (score 2):

The `java.util.concurrent` classes have [special guarantees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) regarding sequencing:

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a `BlockingQueue` *happen-before* actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the `BlockingQueue` in another thread.

This means that you are free to use any kind of mutable object and manipulate it as you wish, then put it into the queue. When it's retrieved, all of the manipulations you've applied will be visible.

(Note more generally that the kind of test you demonstrated can only prove *lack* of safety; in most real-world cases, unsynchronized code works fine 99% of the time. It's that last 1% that bites you.)

Comment: Am I right: if I use simple `HashMap`, update it and put it into say `ArrayBlockingQueue`, it is guaranteed that consuming thread will receive updated `HashMap`? If I see the opposite on production, is it a bug? (openjdk-12.0.2)

Comment: @cybersoft That is exactly the guarantee: operations on the map prior to inserting it in the queue are guaranteed to be visible.

Comment: I already have 2 issues with the same problem - HashMap loses nested HashMap when consuming thread accepts root one. Both servers running Intel Xeon with numa nodes. But java.util.concurrent guarantees "happens-before" on memory... Not for numa cpus? or is it bug in java?

Answer (score 1):

This question has a broad scope.

### Your original scenario

You say :

> [A] map is modified only by single thread, but then it "becomes" read-only

The tricky part is the word "then". When you, the programmer say "then", you refer to "clock time", e.g. i've done this, now do that. But for an incredibly wide variety of reasons, the computer does not "think" (execute code) this way. What happened before, and what happens after need to be "syncrhonized manually" for the computer to see the world the way we see it.

That's the way the Java Memory Model expresses stuff : if you want your objects to behave predictably in a concurrent environment, you have to make sure that you establish "happens before" boundaries.

There are a few things that establish happens before relationships in java code. Simplifying a bit, and just to name a few :

- the order of execution in a single thread (if statements 1 and 2 are executed by the same thread in that order, whatever 1 did is always visible by statement 2)
- When thread t1 `start()`s t2, everything that t1 did before starting t2 is visible by t2. Reciprocally with `join()`
- Same goes with `synchronized`, objects monitors : every action made by a thread inside a sync'd block is visible by another thread that syncs on the same instance
- Same goes with any specialized methods of `java.util.concurrent` classes. e.g Locks and Semaphore, of course, but also collections : if you put an element in a syncrhonized collection, the thread that pulls it out has an happen-before on the thread that put it in.
- If T2 has an happens before with T1, and if T3 has one with T2, then T3 also have it with T1.

So back to  your phrase

> then it "becomes" read-only

It does become read ony. But for the computer to see it, you have to give a meaning to "then"; which is : you have to put an `happen before relationship` in your code.

Later on you state :

> And then puts list into blocking queue

A `java.util.concurrent` queue ? How neat is that! It just so happens that a thread pulling out an object from a concurrent queue has a "happens before" relationship with repsect to the thread that put the said object into the queue.

You have established the realtionship. All mutations made (before) by the thread that put the object into the queue are safely visible by the one that pulls it out. You do not need a `ConcurrentHashMap` in this case (if no other thread mutates the same data of course).

### Your sample code

Your sample code does not use a queue. And it mutates a single map modified by multiple threads (not the other way around as your scenario mentions). So, it's just... not the the same. But either way, your code's fine.

Threads accessing the map do it like so :

```
synchronized (map) {
    map.put(number, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt())
}
```

The `synchornize` provides 1) mutual exclusion of the threads and 2) a happens before. So each thread that enters the synchonization see all that "happened before" in another thread that also syncrhonized on it (which is all of them).

So no problem here.

And then your main thread does :

```
completed.await()
println('Completed:')
map.each { e ->
   println('' + e.key + ': ' + e.value)
}
```

The thing that saves you here is `completed.await()`. This establishes a happens before with every thread that called `countDown()`, which is all of them. So your main thread sees everything that was done by the worker threads. All is fine.

Except... We often forget to check to bootstrap of threads. The first time a worker synchronizes on the map instance, nobody did it before. How come we can be sure that they see a map instance fully initialized and ready.

Well, for two reasons :

1. You initialize the map instance BEFORE calling `thread.start()`, which establishes an happens before. This would be enought
2. Inside your worker threads, you also use latches before starting the work, which then again establish a relationship.

You're doubly safe.

Comment: Now I understand my code snippet is not what I wanted to show, this snippet will never break due to described multiple "happens-before"